# Color property in TInplaceEdit not working

Tags: colors, delphi-2010, delphi-xe, in-place-editor

The following code to change the background color of TInplaceEdit works in Delphi 2010 but does not work in Delphi 11 Community Edition. However the CharCase does work. I looked at many samples addressing this problem but none did work for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
type

  TMyInplaceEdit = class(TInplaceEdit)
  public
    property Color; //redeclare to make public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TTestGrid = class(TStringGrid)
  public
    property InplaceEditor; //redeclare to make public
    function CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit; override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    TestGrid: TTestGrid;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TMyInplaceEdit.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Color := clMoneyGreen;
  CharCase := ecUpperCase;
end;

function TTestGrid.CreateEditor: TInplaceEdit;
begin
  inherited;// same without this line
  Result := TMyInplaceEdit.Create(self);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TestGrid := TTestGrid.Create(Self);
  TestGrid.Parent := Self;
  TestGrid.Show;
  TestGrid.Options := [goFixedVertLine, goFixedHorzLine, goVertLine,   goHorzLine, goEditing, goTabs];

end;
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but why you are calling `inherited` in your `CreateEditor()` override? That does not belong there, get rid of it. You are letting the grid create the default `TInplaceEdit` and then ignore it for your own editor, so you are just wasting resources.

Comment: @Remy. I deleted the inherited as per your first comment and eliminated seClient and and seFont. Still no good. The color does not show up.

Comment: I posted an answer explaining what is happening and how to work around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there was no Delphi 2011, let alone a Community Edition of it.  The next version after Delphi 2010 was Delphi XE.  The first Community Edition was Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.  Perhaps you meant Delphi 11 instead (ie, the current Community Edition version)?

In any case, the reason your editor's `Color` is being ignored is because after `CreateEditor()` returns, the grid sets the editor's `Color` to match the grid's `Color` (it also sets the editor's `Font` and `StyleElements` to match the grid's, too).

This behavior was added in Delphi XE3, which is why it does not happen in Delphi 2010.

Every time the grid updates the editor, it resets the editor's `Color` (and `Font` and `StyleElements`) to match the grid's values, making it more difficult to customize the editor the way you want.  However, I was able to achieve what you want by simply having the editor handle the `CM_COLORCHANGED` notification to change the `Color` back to `clMoneyGreen`, eg:

```pascal
type
  TMyInplaceEdit = class(TInplaceEdit)
  protected
    procedure CMColorChanged(var Message: TMessage); message CM_COLORCHANGED;
  ...
  end;

procedure TMyInplaceEdit.CMColorChanged(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  Color := clMoneyGreen;
  // or here, it doesn't matter either way...
  // inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Using OnDrawCell of the grid to change the color of the selected cell now gives me the same result as my previous code in Delphi 2010

Comment: @Rudi Doing that will color the cell itself, not the Inplace editor on top of the cell. You asked about the editor, not the cell. Two completely different things.

Comment: Agreed. My question was not very clear. My aim is to have the same color for a selected cell and the editor whilst in input mode (goEditing set to true).